# Mutation GraphQL map an Array to java.util.Set

Tags: java, graphql, spring-graphql

With spring-graphql 1.0.1, I am trying to map an array of String `[String]` to a `SortedSet` in a GraphQL Mutation but I get an error.

> Property referenced in indexed property path 'names[0]' is neither an
> array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [[]]

How to specify the conversion from a String array of a Input type to a SortedSet ?

Here is my *schema.graphqls*

```
type Mutation {
    save(person: PersonInput): Person
}

input PersonInput {
    id: String
    names: [String]
}

Type Person {
    id: String
    names: [String]
}
```

```
@Data
public class Person {
  private String id;
  private SortedSet names;
}
```

The mutation Query :

```
mutation {
    save( person: {  id: "1", names: ["A","B"]} ){
        id
        names
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with [spring-graphql 1.1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/releases/tag/v1.1.0)